# R leaflet remove attribution prefix

Tags: leaflet-r, attribution

I am trying to edit the attribution in R leaflet. I am aware of the option to remove the attribution with

```
leaflet::leafletOptions(attributionControl=T)
```

but I would like to keep the attribution, without its naive prefix 'leaflet'. when I do

```
addTiles(urlTemplate = "", attribution = "my attribution")
```

I still have the prefix 'leaflet'.

Is there a way to include keep 'my attribution'? It can be done post hoc by editing the html but I'd rather do it within R.